# Json with different types in fieds to java object

Tags: java, json, object, gson, pojo

I try convert this json in a java object with `Gson`. How can to convert the field "Content"?
Sometimes is a string and others is a object with two fields.

```
"content": "TODO List",
```

or

```
"content": {
      "one": "one",
       "other": "other"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to following question, might help to solves your problem.

[How to handle different data types with same attribute name with Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758872/how-to-handle-different-data-types-with-same-attribute-name-with-gson)